# Simplification problem for complex expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I have a complex expression. Where the variable(s) is(are) real. Even after specifying that the variables are real, it doesn't seem to affect the result.
Here `k` is real, but the expression comes like.

```
H12[k_] = {{-(1/4) Sqrt[-E^(
    2 I k)] (4 π - Arg[E^(I k)/Sqrt[-E^(2 I k)]] - 
     Arg[E^(-I k) Sqrt[-E^(2 I k)]]) Conjugate[Sqrt[-E^(2 I k)]], (
  I E^(I k) (Arg[E^(I k)/Sqrt[-E^(2 I k)]] - 
     Arg[E^(-I k) Sqrt[-E^(2 I k)]]))/(
  4 Sqrt[-E^(2 I k)])}, {1/4 I E^(
   I k) (Arg[E^(I k)/Sqrt[-E^(2 I k)]] - 
     Arg[E^(-I k) Sqrt[-E^(2 I k)]]) Conjugate[Sqrt[-E^(2 I k)]], 
  1/4 (-4 π + Arg[E^(I k)/Sqrt[-E^(2 I k)]] + 
     Arg[E^(-I k) Sqrt[-E^(2 I k)]])}};
DH12[k_] = FullSimplify[D[H12[k],k];
```

In the result you get `Derivative[1][Conjugate]` and `Derivative[1][Abs]`. Eventhough, `k` is real. Is there a way to get out of it. Later, I need to integrate the expression with some other functions because of this problem ,I am not able to do that. Even if I try integrating it just goes on for running..

```
Simplify[DH12[k], {k, z} ∈ Reals], {k, -π, π}]
```

After sometime the result comes out symbolically,
`\!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(∫\), \(-π\), \(π\)]
\*FractionBox[\(1\), \(4\)]\(\ \)\)...`

Comment: How did you generate this matrix? It seems to be real but this is not obvious since you have entries like Conjugate[Sqrt[-E^(2 I k)]], which is complex even for real k.

Comment: @Fabian This bit is from a code(working on it). Is there a way to avoid such `Derivative[1][Conjugate]` get some answer out of it.

Comment: I dont know what you mean by Derivative[1][Conjugate] where do you see this?

Comment: I see this matrix: $$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -\frac{1}{4} i \left(-\arg \left(\frac{e^{i k}}{\sqrt{-e^{2 i k}}}\right)-\arg
   \left(e^{-i k} \sqrt{-e^{2 i k}}\right)+4 \pi \right) \left(e^{-2 \Im(k)}-e^{2 i
   k} \text{Conjugate}'\left(\sqrt{-e^{2 i k}}\right)\right) & 0 \\
 \frac{e^{i k-2 \Im(k)} \left(\arg \left(\frac{e^{i k}}{\sqrt{-e^{2 i
   k}}}\right)-\arg \left(e^{-i k} \sqrt{-e^{2 i k}}\right)\right) \left(e^{2 i
   \Re(k)} \text{Conjugate}'\left(\sqrt{-e^{2 i k}}\right)-1\right)}{4 \sqrt{-e^{2 i
   k}}} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: @Fabian Conjugate′ is actually `Derivative[1][Conjugate]`

Answer (score 2):

```
H12[k_] = {{-(1/4) Sqrt[-E^(2 I k)] (4 π - Arg[E^(I k)/Sqrt[-E^(2 I k)]] -
        Arg[E^(-I k) Sqrt[-E^(2 I k)]]) Conjugate[
      Sqrt[-E^(2 I k)]], (I E^(I k) (Arg[E^(I k)/Sqrt[-E^(2 I k)]] - 
         Arg[E^(-I k) Sqrt[-E^(2 I k)]]))/(4 Sqrt[-E^(2 I k)])}, {1/
      4 I E^(I k) (Arg[E^(I k)/Sqrt[-E^(2 I k)]] - 
       Arg[E^(-I k) Sqrt[-E^(2 I k)]]) Conjugate[Sqrt[-E^(2 I k)]], 
    1/4 (-4 π + Arg[E^(I k)/Sqrt[-E^(2 I k)]] + 
       Arg[E^(-I k) Sqrt[-E^(2 I k)]])}};
```

Plotting indicates that the terms are real and constant.

```
Plot[Evaluate@Flatten@H12[k], {k, -Pi, Pi},
 PlotStyle -> {{Thick, AbsoluteDashing[{20, 20}]}, {Thick, DotDashed}, 
   AbsoluteDashing[{20, 20}], Dotted},
 Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
 WorkingPrecision -> 20,
 PlotPoints -> 200,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[Automatic, {0.75, 0.5}]]
```

[image]

The constant values are

```
SeedRandom[0];
Table[H12[RandomInteger[{-10, 10}]] // Simplify // ComplexExpand // 
   Simplify, {20}] // Union

(* {{{-π, -(π/4)}, {-(π/4), -π}}} *)
```

**EDIT:** Or using rationalized random reals

```
SeedRandom[0];
Table[H12[RandomReal[{-10., 10.}] // Rationalize[#, 0] &] // 
     Simplify // ComplexExpand // FullSimplify, {20}] // Union

(* {{{-π, -(π/4)}, {-(π/4), -π}}} *)
```

For general k, looking at the series expansion

```
Assuming[Element[k, Reals], order = 50; 
 Map[(Series[#, {k, 0, order}] // Normal) &,
  (H12[k] // ComplexExpand[#, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] & // 
    Simplify), {2}]]

(* {{-π, -(π/4)}, {-(π/4), -π}} *)
```

The derivatives are zero.

Comment: Impressive. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the expression as H12[k] is actually constant:

`H12[k_]={{-π, -π/4}, {(-π/4), -π}}`

So the derivatives should be zero.

Comment: How to get this result? Thanks

Comment: I just simplified the entries term by term. So e.g. I E^(I k) Conjugate[Sqrt[-E^(2 I k)]] = -1 or "Sqrt[-E^(2 I k)] Conjugate[Sqrt[-E^(2 I k)]] // FullSimplify" which gives E^(-2 Im[k]) so this zero.